# $\sum_{c \in \bigcup_i C_i} \lambda(c) c=0$ $\implies$ $\lambda(c) \not= 0$ for finitely many $c_{i_1}, ..., c_{i_m}$ in $\bigcup_i C_i$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space, $A$ the collection of all linearly independent subsets of $A$ partially ordered by inclusion $\subset$ and $(C_i)_{i \in I}$ a chain in $A$.

If $\lambda: \bigcup_i C_i \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ (where $\mathbb{F}$ is a field, e.g. $\mathbb{R}$) is "essentially zero" and $\sum_{c \in \cup_i C_i} \lambda(c) c=0$, then $\lambda(c) \not= 0$ for finitely many $c_{i_1}, ..., c_{i_m}$ in $\bigcup_i C_i$?

Why?

I don't understand why must the finitely many $c_{i_1}, ..., c_{i_m}$ exist, because I thought $\sum_{c \in \cup_i C_i}$ would cover all $c$s that there are and thus there wouldn't be $c$s for which $\lambda(c) \not= 0$.

Or perhaps I misunderstand, what "essentially zero" means.

---

This appears here, end of p. 1.

https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~tyson/595chapter1.pdf

Comment: This is not clear.  What are the $C_i$?  What is $\mathbb F$?  What does the sum mean if $\lambda (c)$ is non-zero infinitely often?

Comment: Well, not sure "essentially zero" is standard usage but I'd guess it has to mean "$0$ except at finitely many values".  Otherwise, you have to state what you mean by the non-trivial infinite sum.

Comment: @lulu Yea. Essentially what they're doing there is to assume the set as "linearly dependent" (not all scalars zero) and then go on to prove that in fact it's "linearly independent" (all scalars equal to zero).

Comment: @lulu But why can one assume that there exists a finite set of non-zero $\lambda$? Why isn't it possible that all $\lambda$s be non-zero and there'd be infinite amount of them?

Comment: One can assume anything, that's not my point. I have no idea, for example, what you (or whomever posed this problem) wants to assume.  But an infinite sum of non-zero terms in a field is not, in general, defined...so if you intend such a sum, you have to give it a precise meaning.

Comment: @lulu Well the proof I reference here only considers this particular case. Is it the only case that exists then? Or does it have some hidden assumption about only considering finite vector spaces?

Comment: I haven't read the notes you link to, and I do not intend to.  I expect that they assume that the sum is finite!  I really can't imagine what else they might have assumed but, honestly, it's for you (or them) to declare the assumptions.  We aren't mind readers.

Comment: Don't be misled by the fact that we sometimes attach a meaning to, say, an infinite sum of rationals.  That's not really a field-theoretic business.  It depends on our chosen topology for the rationals (usually viewing them as a subset of $\mathbb R$) and is very, very carefully defined.

Comment: @lulu It could be also that the finiteness comes from $A$, which is "the collection of all linearly independent subsets of $V$". I think it could be impossible for linearly independent sets to be infinite cardinality, because how would one be able to show all the scalars as zero then, if one cannot reach all the elements in the set?

Comment: A vector space, over $\mathbb R$ say, has a great many linearly independent subsets.

Comment: Despite what I said earlier, I did look (quickly) at the notes.  I don't see any ambiguity at all.  The text clearly says "Let $S$ be any set. A set $R \subset  S$ is called cofinite if $S -R$ is a finite set. A function
$\lambda: S\to \mathbb F$ is called essentially zero if ${s : \lambda(s) = 0} $ is a cofinite subset of $S$.

Comment: @lulu Thank you. That notion is related to this: http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~kesmith/infinite.pdf